# Error Checking With VBScript Err Object

Tags: vbscript, error-handling

With the following block of code, which accesses an html span element, I am unable to check for errors. When I leave the input box empty and press "ok," the value of Err.Number doesn't change. I have user error checking enabled (On Error Resume Next) and I am checking to make sure that Err.Number is not equal to 0 (an error is ocurring). The error is being thrown, but the value of Err.Number is not changing, and this happens both when On Error Resume Next is on as well as when it is off). By the way, what is the default value of Err.Number? How does that value differ from the value of Err.Number after the Err object is cleared? If I am doing anything wrong or stating any wrong information, please inform me.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim updateRate
updateRate = 0
RatePrompt()
Sub RatePrompt
    updateRate = InputBox("Please enter an update rate (milliseconds)",     "Update Rate")

If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear()
    MsgBox "No Input Was Specified. Please Specify An Input."
    RatePrompt()
Else If updateRate > 2000 then
    rateDecision = MsgBox ("Consider entering a lower update rate" & vbCrLf & "Would you like to revise update rate?", _
    vbYesNo, "Quiclock Alert")
    If rateDecision = vbYes then 
        RatePrompt()
    End If
Else If updateRate < 0 then
    MsgBox "Update Rate Not Valid. The Default Value of 0 Milliseconds Will Be Used."
    updateRate = 0
Else If updateRate = "" then
    MsgBox "Update Rate Adjustment Cancelled. The Default Value of 0 Milliseconds Will Be Used."
    updateRate = 0
Else 

End If
End If
End If
End If
End Sub

TimerStart()

Sub TimerStart
    timerID = window.setTimeout("TimeUpdate", updateRate, "VBScript")
End Sub

Sub TimeUpdate
    clockOutput.innerHTML = Time()
    window.clearTimeout(timerID)
    TimerStart()
End Sub
```

I have spent a large amount of time researching this problem, but have not come to a conclusion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you checking the error value to determine if a valid input was made? Also, it's not a good idea to recursively call your subroutine. You could run out of stack space and your original execution point will continue after your recursive call finishes. Just use a `Do While` loop until you get valid input.

Comment: @Bond I am checking the error value to see if the inputbox ok button was pressed without any content in the inputbox. It will throw an error if this is the case.

Comment: Just check for `Len(updateRate) > 0`. If so, you got input. You've got a slew of other errors, as well. Your `Else If` statements should be `ElseIf`, for example. That's why you needed all the `End If`'s at the end to make it work.

Comment: @Bond Thank you so much. I am very new to VBScript programming.

Comment: @Bond Applying the Len(updateRate) doesn't seem to fix things. It just makes it harder to distinguish between a press of the "ok" on the inputbox and a press of the "cancel" when the inputbox is empty. The cancel always returns an empty string, whereas the "ok" throws an error and returns an empty string. I want to capture that error so that I can distinguish between the two.

Comment: You can use `IsEmpty()` to test for cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Try next *logic skelet* for your script:

```
Dim updateRate, rateRevision
updateRate = InputBox("Please enter an update rate (milliseconds)", "Update Rate")
If IsEmpty( updateRate) Then
  '`Cancel` (or equivalent `Esc` or red `×`) pressed/clicked
Else
  If IsNumeric( updateRate) Then
    updateRate = CLng( updateRate)   'convert string to a Variant of subtype Long
    If updateRate > 2000 Then
      ' do not bother a user by an additional input: offer a value change right now
      rateRevision = InputBox ("Consider entering a lower update rate" _
        & vbCrLf & "Would you like to revise update rate?", _
          "Quiclock Alert", updateRate)
      If IsNumeric( rateRevision) Then
        rateRevision = CLng( rateRevision)
        If rateRevision > 0 Then updateRate = rateRevision
      Else
        ' keep the value > 2000
      End If
    ElseIf updateRate < 0 Then
      updateRate = 0
    Else
      ''
    End If
  Else
    'non-numeric input, use e.g. default value of zero
    updateRate = 0
  End If
  TimerStart()
End If
```

An explanation and observation to the code:

- There is a mistake in the [InputBox Function reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5(v=vs.84).aspx). In fact: if the user clicks **Cancel** (or the red <kbd>×</kbd> or presses <kbd>Esc</kbd>), then the function returns an **empty** value, which *looks like* a zero-length string (`""`) due to automatic subtype conversion. See the `32213674.vbs` script output below.
- [Comparison Operators (VBScript) reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx) shows how expressions are compared or what results from the comparison, depending on the underlying subtype; particularly: if one expression is numeric and the other is a string then **the numeric expression is less than the string expression**.

`32213674.vbs` **script**:

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim sValInput
Call doOutput( True, sValInput)
Do While True 
  sValInput = InputBox( _
    "Please enter any value (and `OK`) to see its features:" & vbCR _
      & "a date-like value, e.g. " & FormatDateTime( Now, vbShortDate) & vbCR _
      & "a time-like value, e.g. " & FormatDateTime( Now, vbShortTime) & vbCR _
      & "a number-like value, e.g. 123456" & vbCR _
      & "a string of your choice" & vbCR _
      & "an empty string (i.e. only click `OK`)" & vbCR _
      & "or press `Esc` or click red `×` or `Cancel` button to exit the loop" _
      , "InputBox test loop")
  Call doOutput( False, sValInput)
  If IsEmpty( sValInput) Then Exit Do
Loop

Sub doOutput( bHeader, sVal)
  If Instr(1, Wscript.FullName, "cscript.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    If bHeader Then
      Wscript.Echo sHead()
    Else
      Wscript.Echo sLine( sVal)
    End If
  Else
    If bHeader Then
    Else
      MsgBox( sHead() & vbCR & sLine( sVal))
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Function sHead()
  sHead = "Empty?" & vbTab & "Number?" & vbTab & _
    "Date?" & vbTab & "VarType" & vbTab & "TypeName" & "[value]" 
End Function

Function sLine( sValue)
  sLine = IsEmpty( sValue) & vbTab & IsNumeric( sValue) & vbTab & _
    IsDate( sValue) & vbTab & VarType( sValue) & vbTab & _
    TypeName( sValue) & vbTab & "[" & sValue & "]"
End Function
```

**Output**:

```
==>cscript //NOLOGO D:\VB_scripts\SO\32213674.vbs
Empty?  Number? Date?   VarType TypeName[value]
False   False   True    8       String  [2015-08-26]
False   False   True    8       String  [22:01:05]
False   True    False   8       String  [123456]
False   False   False   8       String  [qwertz]
False   False   False   8       String  []
True    True    False   0       Empty   []
```